# How to set up morphTo() parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

Method signature of morphTo() is:

```
public function morphTo($name = null, $type = null, $id = null, $ownerKey = null)
{
    ....
```

What does $name, $type, $id, $ownerKey mean in the laravel documentation example?

> posts
>       id - integer
>       name - string
>
> users
>       id - integer
>       name - string
>
> images
>       id - integer
>       url - string
>       imageable_id - integer
>       imageable_type - string

Answer (score 3):

If you follow Laravel's naming convention then you don't need to add any params to the method.

Here is a breakdown of the params for the `morphTo` method:

- `$name`
  This is used to define the relationship name (if it's different to the method name). This is also used to figure out the name of the polymorphic fields in the database (if not passed as `$type` or `$id`). If `$name` is left as `null` it will use the method name of the relationship i.e.

  ```
  public function imageable() 
  {
      return $this->morphTo();
  }
  ```

  The above is the same as writing:

  ```
  public function imageable() 
  {
      return $this->morphTo('imageable');
  }
  ```

  This will tell Laravel to use `imageable_id` and `imageable_type` as for the database field names.

  ```
  public function imageModel()
  ```

  would result in the relationship being accessed as `$model->imageModel`, however, the database field names it would use would be `image_model_id` and `image_model_type`.
- `$type` and `$id`
  These can be used to respectively override the fields names that would be assumed from the 1st param e.g. if your field names were something like `owner_id` and `owner_model` but you still wanted the relationship to be imageable then you could do:

  ```
  public function imageable() 
  {
      return $this->morphTo('imageable', 'owner_model', 'owner_id');
  }
  ```
- `$ownerKey`
  This is simply the field name on the related table. You would use this to tell Laravel to use a different field name to the one that is defined as the `$primaryKey` for the related instance.

Comment: Is it valid the idea that setting this values I can avoid calling more methods so the execution is a little more fast?